# htaccess redirects from URLs on one domain to the root of another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently what is happening is people are accessing old URLs from google like icpaweb.com/site/pages/about-us/ and being sent to their corresponding urls on icpaweb.org : icpaweb.org/site/pages/about-us.

What I want is to send people from: icpaweb.com/site/pages/about-us to icpaweb.org/ without any of the succeeding url segments.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use an .htaccess file, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} icpaweb.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://icpaweb.org/ [R=301,L]
```

That will 301 redirect all requests for  **icpaweb.com** to the index root of **icpaweb.org**. If you don't want 301, it can just be `R`.

You'll need to replace or turn off whatever mechanism is doing your redirecting now, they may not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use an url rewrite rule.
2 steps:

- Write a RewriteCond so that the following rewrite rule only apply for url with host being icpaweb.com like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} icpaweb.com$ [NC]` The [NC] is for case insensitive match
- Write a rewrite rule that convert all input to what you want like `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://icpaweb.org/ [L]`The [L] is to stop the rewriting to this rule if rule executed.